# What is the difference between cookies and web beacon?

Tags: google-chrome, security, session, web, cookies

I am trying to make web tracking referral system, i learn a many ways to do that, such as cookies, web beacon, and web fingerprinting, but i don't find satisfying answer about difference of cookies and web beacon. So what is the difference between web beacon and cookies?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to review the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what sort of question you can ask here and the best way to ask it so you get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

> Web beacons, which are also known as clear GIFs, Web bugs or pixel
>   tags, are often used in combination with cookies. They are images
>   (often transparent) that are part of Web pages. At Monster, Web
>   beacons allow us to count users who have visited certain pages and to
>   generate statistics about how our site is used. They are not used to
>   access personally identifiable information.
>
> Unlike cookies, you cannot decline Web beacons. However, setting your
>   browser to decline cookies or to prompt you for a response will keep
>   Web beacons from tracking your activity.

Check this link: [What You Need to Know About Cookies and Web Beacons.](https://www.monster.com/career-advice/article/cookies-and-web-beacons#:~:text=Web%20beacons%2C%20which%20are%20also,are%20part%20of%20Web%20pages.&text=Unlike%20cookies%2C%20you%20cannot%20decline%20Web%20beacons.)

Your question is so general. I suggest you check these link and then go for more ask more specific questions if you has some:

- [Cookies and Web Beacons](https://gi.org/cookies-and-web-beacons/)
- [Cookie & Web Beacon Policy](https://www.cerillion.com/Legal/Cookies)
- [COOKIES, WEB BEACONS AND OTHER TECHNOLOGIES](https://www.logitechg.com/en-gb/legal/cookie-policy.html)
- [5 Things You Need to Know About Beacon Technology](https://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2018/10/04/beacon-technology)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and recomendation!